# Galaxy Tab2 fails to see functioning Netgear router

Tags: wi-fi, samsung-galaxy-tab-10, router

We have a Samsung Galaxy Tab2 10.1. It previously connected fine via Wi-Fi to our Netgear router from anywhere in the house. Last night, it stopped connecting and no longer displays the router in the `available routers` list, even though many neighbour's routers are visible (but password protected, of course).

I have rebooted the router. We have four Mac laptops and two iPhones, and all connect wirelessly to the router without problems.  I have entered the SSID and password manually (and correctly) several times, but no joy. The Galaxy simply states `Out of range` under the SSID of our router.  Not so surprising as the machine fails to "see" our router at all, even though the router is broadcasting its existence to the Macs just fine.

One last thing: the Galaxy sees fewer of the neighbour's routers than the Macs, and shows a weaker signal strength for those it does see - but I have tried it right next to our router without any recognition. The Macs see our router as full strength from most of the house.  Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Check the MAC address on your tablet, and compare it to the MAC address listed for the tablet on your hot spot in the configuration window. If the two MAC addresses are not the same, your hot spot will not connect and an IP address will not be assigned.

I am currently experiencing this problem where something keeps changing the MAC address in my tablet . I have not been able to resolve it, including performing a full factory reset.
I am certainly open to any advice or suggestions on this issue.
Thanks